# How to hide invisible Elements in CSS Animation?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations

I have coded a Bootstrap 4 animated card: https://codepen.io/Steven2105/pen/ZEGLWma.

The card shows a heading by default, the card text should be invisible.
Once you hover over the card the text also should move up and be visible.

So my question is, how can I hide the card text, only show the heading and make it visible once hovered.

If you scroll down on [this page](https://www.heidelbergcement.com/en), you should also see such cards and I want them to be like them.

```css
.card-body {
  margin-top: -58px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 82, 204, 0.7);
}

.card:hover .card-body {
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-fill-mode:both;
  margin-top: 0;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-body {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 82, 204, 0.7);
}

.card-text {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.card:hover .card-text {
  display: block;
  max-height: 150px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 1s ease-out; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your answer works best so far, however if you have multiple cards the will stack behind each other, so you can't see them. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The card has a position absolute, changed to a relative. Please try it.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.card-body {
  margin-top: -58px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 82, 204, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 82, 204, 0.7);
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.card:hover .card-body {
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-fill-mode:both;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.card-text{
  display:none;
}

.card:hover .card-text{
  display:block;
}

.card:hover .card-body{
  position:relative !important;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, do you also know how to hide the blue box below the card? So that only the image with the heading is shown by default.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the last 2 responses. I come to you to offer an excellent version of this UX card. I did this on codepen a few months ago and tried to put a cool effect on the card. Maybe my participation will help you! 
My codepen : https://codepen.io/ZellRDesign/pen/MPbRyr

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700);

body{
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-size:16px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.link{
    display: block;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform :  translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) translateZ(0);
  width: 370px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(black,0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}

.card a{
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.card:hover{
  box-shadow:0 0 50px rgba(black,0.3);
}

.card-date{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(68, 105, 176);
  border-radius: 50%;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.card-date-month{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:10px;
}

.card-date-day{
    font-size:14px;
}

.card-thumb{
  height: 245px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512036849132-48508f294900?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=af817fb1a3fe6d229f4bfc0b8d60441a&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  transition: height 0.5s;
  
  img{
    display:block;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  }
}

.card:hover .card-thumb{
    height: 130px;
}

.card-body{
  position: relative;
  height: 105px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  padding:20px;
  transition: height 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .card-body{
    height: 220px;
}

.card-title{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.card-description{
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #666C74;
  line-height: 27px;
  opacity:0;
  transform: translateY(45px);
  transition: opacity 0.5s -0.2s, transform 0.5s -0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.card:hover .card-description{
    opacity:1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition-delay: 0.2s;  
}
```

```html
<article class="card">
  <header class="card-thumb">
    <a href="#" class="link"></a>
  </header>
  <date class="card-date">
    <span class="card-date-day">11</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="card-date-month">Juin</span>
  </date>
  
  <div class="card-body">
    <h2 class="card-title"><a href="#">We're on a highway to hell!</a></h2>
    <p class="card-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit cumque non commodi, modi recusandae cupiditate ipsa ab soluta. Illum, dolore.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

NB : this link can provide you an awesome tutoriel to do this (in French): https://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/card-ui-629

Comment: Your solution is also very nice, but doesn't work with multiple cards and is pure CSS. Thank you, nevertheless :)

Comment: it work for multiple card , look at this : https://codepen.io/ZellRDesign/pen/MPbRyr , you just need to remove the 3 firsts line on .card css

Comment: Okay. But note that the text interferes now with the heading.

Comment: Not for me, can u explain the bug ? Which browser do you use ?

Comment: I'm using the latest Chrome Browser. It works when you have a relatively large display however on normal-sized and smaller displays it interferes.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the **visibility Property**

**Example 1:**

```
h2.a {
   visibility: visible;
}

h2.b {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Example 2:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <h1>Link Hover Here</h1>

  <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est, aut! Ea eos 
   voluptate numquam sapiente cum, enim facilis a cumque dolore, modi, autem possimus 
   voluptatem architecto ratione sequi dolores ipsa.</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h3{
    visibility: hidden;
}

h1:hover {
  color: #ff0000;
}

.container:hover h3{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

**CSS visibility Property:** https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/abOpNgR